# should multiple calls to std::find be avoided due to computational expense or would this be an acceptable case?

Tags: c++

I was trying to come up with an easy and efficient way of parsing command line arguments without sacrificing safety.  I came up with the code below which, so far seems to be quite robust.  My biggest concern is executing std::find over and over again might be computationally expensive.  With two arguments its probably not really a big deal.  With 20, it might be.

Would this be an inefficient way of parsing arguments?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  bool continueProcessing = true;
  std::vector<std::string> args;
  for(int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
  {
    args.push_back(std::string(argv[i]));
  }

  if(std::find(args.begin(), args.end(), "-h") != args.end())
  {
    /* Help entry goes here*/
    continueProcessing = false;
  }
  if(std::find(args.begin(), args.end(), "-o") != args.end())
  {
    outputFile = const_cast<char*>((*++std::find(args.begin(),args.end(), "-o")).c_str())
  }
}
```

Comment: make code that works, is clean and easy to read. If it seems to be slow then revisit and always use a profiler

Comment: Your code first copies the argument vector to a vector of strings, then continues with find() and then assigns the result to a plain pointer, casting away the `const`, so it has a bunch of problems, some of which are even performance-related. That said, how many arguments do you expect? Anyhow, you are asking whether "foo" is slow, and the only answer to that is that you should measure it. Unless the performance causes a bottleneck, go for the clearest and cleanest code!

Comment: Currently, as its used in a very small program, it is not slow.  The reason for the question is I want to know if the code is worth saving, or would I have complications in larger applications.  Converting command line arguments to strings and passing them to a vector seemed like the cleanest way to parse it.  I could have done it with c strings but it wouldn't have been as clean.  I'm not very happy about the const _cast but, it seems that in this scenario, it shouldn't present any problems.

Comment: After doing nothing for 30 seconds waiting for someone to type a command you are worried about an extra 100 nsec of processing?

Comment: The larger a program gets, the more important it becomes to not do hacks like `const_cast`, in particular not for mundane tasks like command line parsing. You asking whether "the code is worth saving, or would I have complications in larger applications" is thus answered with a simple "no".

Answer (score 1):

Let me answer the underlying question.

Parsing arguments isn't fun and you should use some code that some other dude wrote, see:

[Boost.Program_options](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/program_options.html) (often overkill) or [GNU's Getopt](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) do this very well.

Comment: Boost.Parameter appears to be more for a style of C++ function calls within C++ code. Can it also help with command line arguments? In any case, boost::program_options may also be worth mentioning.

Comment: @aschepler that would be a typo